# The difference between 'is' and 'be'

Tags: meaning

In the picture below, how different is it to say 'Korea's weather be like' from to say 'Korea's weather is like'?

[image]

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212282/be-like-usage

Answer (score 3):

**This is not standard English**.

Standard English would only allow *is* there, and speakers of most varieties of English would not use *be* in this way.

Some varieties of English can use *be* - most notably [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English). I don't know AAVE well enough to know whether this particular sentence is likely.

What this is, is an internet meme: if you search for '"be like" meme', you will find lots of examples.

Comment: A meme-related website such as Know Your Meme will provide lots more information; they have variants such as [bitches be like](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/bitches-be-like) which they date as a meme from 2012, although the phrase is found in older sources e.g. rap songs, and the more recent likes of [evil X be like](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/evil-x-be-like).